# How to convert an M x M pandas DataFrame into an N X 2 Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"type": ["A", "B", "C"],
                   "A": [0, 0, 12],
                   "B": [1, 3, 0],
                   "C": [0, 1, 1]}
)
```

I want to transform this to a DataFrame that is N X 2, where I concatenate the column and `type` values with `" - "` as delimiter. The output should look like this:

```
pair    value
A - A   0
A - B   0
A - C   12
B - A   1
B - B   3
B - C   0
C - A   0
C - B   1
C - C   1
```

I don't know if there is a name for what I want to accomplish (I thought about pivoting but I believe that is something else), so that didn't help me in googling the solution for this. How to solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: Set Index to your key. Stack. Then concatenate.

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars='type')` (joining the first two columns if desired)

Answer (score 1):

1st set index as `type` and then `unstack` and convert the result to dataframe.

**try:**

```
x = df.set_index('type').unstack().to_frame('value')
x.index = x.index.map(' - '.join)
res = x.rename_axis('pair').reset_index()
```

**res:**

```
    pair    value
0   A - A   0
1   A - B   0
2   A - C   12
3   B - A   1
4   B - B   3
5   B - C   0
6   C - A   0
7   C - B   1
8   C - C   1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Only thing is I want the "type" values first in each pair, so the output needs to be exactly as in the post. Could you adapt it to that? Then Ill accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

First melt the column `type`, then join `variable`, and `type` column with a hyphen `-`, and  take the required columns only:

```py
>>> out = df.melt(id_vars='type')
>>> out.assign(pair=out['variable']+'-'+out['type'])[['pair', 'value']]

  pair  value
0  A-A      0
1  A-B      0
2  A-C     12
3  B-A      1
4  B-B      3
5  B-C      0
6  C-A      0
7  C-B      1
8  C-C      1
```